# Issues with cv2.write()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a sign language detection system with tensorflow. But when i try to collect images from my webcam, i had encountered a syntax error but I am not sure what's the issue.

```
for label in labels:  
    !mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\\'+label} 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
    print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
    time.sleep(5) 
    for imgnum in range(number_imgs): 
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label, label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1(())))    
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        time.sleep(2)
                                 
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    cap.release()
```

I got this particular error message:

```
    cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You did not close all parentheses on the preceding line. Also, your syntax for 'uuid1' is wrong (it does not require a tuple as input).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, that was a silly mistake from me. Right now, there seems to be another error popping up. It shows that "NameError: name 'labels' is not defined
"

Comment: Well, is it defined? It is not defined on the snippet above, but I was assuming it was defined somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, the problem is solved now, it seems that when using jupyter notebook, I need to run each sections of the code in order for it to work as intended.